# Is Dynamic Traffic Format supported by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, format, traffic

I have to merge (Dynamic Traffic FORMAT) DTF file into QGIS. This data is only available from NAVTEQ or TOM TOM. When I have searched ArcGIS network analysis tool, there is a clear option for adding a DTF file. I don't see the same feature for QGIS. I would like to know if there is a similar option in QGIS.